# Проверить на bash существование psql базы

Tags: postgresql, bash

Нужно в `bash` скрипте проверить сущетсвует указанная `psql` база или нет. Есть какие-то штатные средства?

Для файлов есть конструкция:  `if [ -f $FILE ]; then`
Для psql - возможно есть что-то свое. Либо возможно стоит копать в сторону физического поиска самих бд в файловом формате?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Видимо вам нужно что-то вроде этого:

```bash
if psql -lqt | cut -d \| -f 1 | grep -qw <db_name>; then
   #база существует

else
 #база не существует

fi
```

Оригинал [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14549270/check-if-database-exists-in-postgresql-using-shell)

Comment: Akalnq, да, такой вариант практически подходит! Единственное только грип с ключами `-qw` мне ничего не отдает толкового. Если грепать совсем без ключей - то работает, но нет однозначности) тоесть если будет 3 базы а-ля db_test, db_test1, db_test2 - то по запросу db_test я увижу все три)